# Logging in to the Rails Devise app using QR Code scanning from mobile app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, qr-code, restful-authentication

How should one implement the following authentication flow?

1. The user navigates to the web app
2. The web app asks them to log in
3. The user takes his mobile phone and opens the mobile app (specially designed to complement the web app) and opens a special QR Code scanner built in the mobile app
4. The user scans the QR Code displayed on the web app's page
5. The user gets logged in

---

I've seen such functionality in a couple of websites and now I'm interested in implementing it in my own app.

I've created a Rails app with API and OAuth2.0 provider using `Grape` and `Doorkeeper`, and I also use `Devise` to authenticate users.

As far as I can tell, having read several articles (like [this one](https://galois.com/blog/2011/01/quick-authentication-using-mobile-devices-and-qr-codes/) and [this one](http://blog.self.li/post/14864315302/qr-login-howto)), the QR Code generated on the web page should contain a special authentication token or something.

If we assume that user's credentials can be stored in the mobile app's storage, how would such kind of authentication work without having user's session|cookie stored in the browser and server?

Of course, there will be a normal log-in form if the user doesn't want to log in using QR Code.

---

Are there any tips on implementing that? Maybe there's a good Rails-specific article which I couldn't find? Or maybe someone has already tried implementing such functionality?

I'd really appreciate any tips, pieces of advice, code examples and ideas on that.

Comment: did you find anything regarding that issue?